# How to show a process list using Ansible ad-hoc?

Tags: linux, ansible, adhoc, processlist

How to show a process list using ansible **ad-hoc command**?

Comment: [SOLVED] ansible <"hosts"> -m shell -a 'ps -ef'

Answer (score 2):

**Ansible Ad-hoc Syntax:**

ansible <"hosts"> [-m <"module_name">] -a <"arguments"> -u  [--become]

**Ex:**
ansible <"hosts"> -m shell -a 'ps -ef'

**Hosts**: It can be any entry in the inventory file. For specifying all hosts in inventory, use all or '*'. Wild card patterns are also accepted.

**module_name**: It's an optional parameter. There are hundreds of modules available in Ansible. By default it is a command. For example, shell, copy, yum, apt, file.

**Arguments**: We should pass values that are required by the module. It may change according to the module used.

**Username**: It specifies the user account in which Ansible can execute commands. User account, SSH.

**Become**: It's an optional parameter specified when we want to execute operations that need sudo privilege. By default become is false.

**PS:** If you put a -c option, then Ansible will do a dry run of the command. It will not actually be applied on the nodes.

Comment: ansible <"hosts"> -m shell -a 'ps -ef' worked. Thank you for the answer!